# Move all files from multiple subfolders into the parent folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found a nice script at https://superuser.com/questions/999922/move-all-files-from-multiple-subfolders-into-the-parent-folder

The main problem is I need a script which works for every subfolder and moves all files to the folder above from the Flacroot directory as initial point. For example Album1 --> Re-Encode, all content off Re-Encode should be moved to Album1 and that for every Album directory.

```
@echo off

FOR /R "C:\Source Folder" %%i IN (*.png) DO MOVE "%i" "C:\Staging Folder"
```

This script cannot do it for every subfolder. Has someone has an idea how that could be solved?

From:

```
|Flacroot
|    |Album1
|    |      |Re-Encode
|    |      |          |*.*
|Flacroot
|    |Album2
|    |      |Re-Encode
|    |      |          |*.*
|Flacroot
|    |Album3
|    |      |Re-Encode
|    |      |          |*.*
```

to:

```
|Flacroot
|    |Album1
|    |      |Re-Encode, *.*
|Flacroot
|    |Album2
|    |      |Re-Encode, *.*
|Flacroot
|    |Album3
|    |      |Re-Encode, *.*
```

Original and edited structure:

```
D:.
│   cuerenamer.bat
│
└───!Onmyōza
    │
    ├───Onmyo-Za - Welter of Hundred Demons
    │   │   Front.jpg
    │   │
    │   ├───Re-Encode
    │   │       01. Song1.flac
    │   │       02. Song2.flac
    │   │
    │   └───Scans
    │           02.jpg
    │           03.jpg
    │
    │───Onmyo-Za - Ninja Magic Story of Voluptuous Flower 
    │   │   Front.jpg
    │   │
    │   ├───Re-Encode
    │   │       01. Song1.flac
    │   │       02. Song2.flac
    │   │
    │   └───Scans
    │           02.jpg
    │           03.jpg
    │           04.jpg
```

Oh and important the `Scans` folder should be excluded and should not be touched. I hope this structure explains that good enough.

The script should run in the parent folder `!Onmyōza` and move the files as described.

Thank you!

Comment: have a look at this answer, seems to be what you are after.
https://superuser.com/questions/1146686/move-all-files-within-subfolders-to-parent-folder

Comment: Instead of painting a nice tree use `tree.exe  /F .`to show the real tree, if necessary shortened or neutralized. If I understand right you want to move all files from the subfolders `Re-Encode` one level up?

Comment: It would also help if your command line names matched the information provided in the tree. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45769903/edit) your question with more understandable information, _do not submit question updates as comments_.

Comment: Ok thanks LotPings that was the idea. Yes all files from the subfolder Re-Encode should be moved one level up.

Comment: Draw Lean, no this script will not work I need that function variable in the parent folder.

Comment: I updated the answer I hope it is now better to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is easy to achieve with the following batch code:

```
@echo off
for /D %%I in ("%~dp0*") do (
    if exist "%%I\Re-Encode\*" (
        move /Y "%%I\Re-Encode\*" "%%I\" 2>nul
        rd "%%I\Re-Encode" 2>nul
    )
)
```

`%~dp0` references the drive and path of the batch file which is expanded to a directory path always ending with a backslash.

Command **FOR** with option `/D` searches for non-hidden directories matching the pattern `*` in directory of the batch file. This means **FOR** processes the directories `Album1`, `Album2` and `Album3` with batch file being in directory `Flacroot` or `Onmyo-Za - Welter of Hundred Demons` and `Onmyo-Za - Ninja Magic Story of Voluptuous Flower` with batch file being in directory `!Onmyōza`.

The **IF** condition checks if there is in current subdirectory of the batch file's directory as found by **FOR** a subdirectory `Re-Encode`.

If there is a subdirectory `Re-Encode`, all files in this subdirectory are moved one directory level up to current subdirectory in batch file directory.

Then the subdirectory `Re-Encode` is removed which works only if it does not contain anymore any files or other subdirectories and not running process use this directory as current directory.

Error messages which could be output because of a file to move already exists in the album directory and being read-only, or the file to move is opened in an application resulting in a sharing access violation, or subdirectory `Re-Encode` is not empty on deletion, ... are suppressed by redirecting them from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explaining `%~dp0`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rd /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`.

Comment: Hello Mofi, thank you so much. This script is real time saver and works like a charme!